# MS Excel 2003 - Simple unselect question in Excel VBA when dealing with shapes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

So I have an excel workbook that has a global mapping scheme in it. So I have a shape for each and every country in excel. Depending on the region select, relative to the data/query, it will shade regions/countries in various ways.

So I know how to manipulate each shape in terms of colors, gradient shading, etc....

What I don't know how to do is "unselect" the shape at the end of the sub routine. My code looks like this (real simple):

```
sheet1.shapes("CountryName").select
selection.shaperange.fill.solid
selection.shaperange.fill.visible = true
selection.shaperange.fill.forecolor.rgb=rgb(110,110,110)
selection.shaperange.fill.onecolorgradiend msogradienthorizontal, 2, 0.45
```

ok so from one shape/country/region to another the "unselect" is not that big of a deal because focus jumps, but at the end????

I have guessed/tried a bunch of stuff but alas no luck

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo in your source last line, ...gradiend --> ...gradient

```
selection.shaperange.fill.onecolorgradienT msogradienthorizontal, 2, 0.45
```

a very simple way of "de-selecting" the shape object would be to add this line of code

```
sheet1.[A1].select
```

this moves the focus to cell A1 in your sheet and hence away fro your object. Very rude, and I don't recommend it. I also don't recommend to "save the current selection" as proposed above as we don't know if the cursor is in a cell or at another (range) object.

The bettwer way is to avoid "selection" completely throughout your script. Asign your shape to an object and manipulate that object (note: I simulated in sheet3 with the first available object in my test), i.e.

```
Sub test()
Dim MyShape As Shape
    Set MyShape = Sheet3.Shapes(1) ' or whatever shape according to the user input
    With MyShape.Fill
        .Solid
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 110, 110)
        .OneColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2, 0.45
    End With
End Sub
```

Even better, if you are processing a list that gives you the name of a shape, do the following

```
Sub Test()
    '
    ' get the shape's name into ShapeName
    ' ...

    ColorShape Sheet3.Shapes(ShapeName)

    ' ...

End Sub

Sub ColorShape(MyShape As Shape)
    With MyShape.Fill
        .Solid
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 110, 110)
        .OneColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2, 0.45
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps
Good luck MikeD

Comment: sweet! this will help a lot. so more questions then: how do I assign the shape as an object?? is it already an object because it's been named? so the last example is something I was already thinking about doing function/subs being called by procedure based on what the relative procedure calling it is. wow this explains a lot to me though, because my little code looks soooo redundant compared to this!!! thanks! :D

Comment: assign shape to object:

1st example: explicitely in asigning the named shape from the "List of Shapes" .... Set Set MyShape = Sheet3.Shapes(1) ... instead of numerical index you can reference by name in a string variable as well

2nd example: implicitely by Sub Test() when handing over the object named "ShapeName" from the list of shapes called "Shapes()" towards the Sub ColorShape.

it's always the same mechanism: objects are arranged in lists and you reference them by an index or a name. that works for shapes, worksheets, cell ranges, etc etc.

hope that helps. Good luck MikeD

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply record the original cell which was selected?

```
Dim oCell as Range
set oCell = activecell

'' Do stuff here

oCell.activate
```

Update: This bit of code records the current selection, then re-selects it after selecting range("A4").  Without knowing what kinds of shapes you have in your workbook, I can't verify that this will work, but it has so far with what I've tested.

```
Set mySel = Application.Selection
[A4].Select
mySel.Select
```

Comment: what if the current selection is not a cell range but another shape object? in this case the selection moves to the cell that was selected BEFORE the selection moved to the recent shape object

Comment: What shape object are you referring to? I created a text label, selected it, then ran this code: Set mySel = Application.Selection   [A4].Select   mySel.Select

Comment: afaiu(nderstand) justin has a lot of shapes in one of his sheets, he could have selected one of these shapes instead of a cell when he fires his coloring procedure, so we cannot asume it is always a cell which is selected. your code would throw him back to the last cell selected before one of the shapes on his sheets was selected

Comment: I realize my 1st answer did, but what about the comment I just made?  That's different. (Edited original answer to include update)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I needed to hide a shape after it was click.  My solution was to use `SendKeys` to escape the selection

```
SendKeys "{Esc}"
```